# Changing shadowRoot.innerHTML stop inherited behavior for attributes and events

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, shadow-dom, custom-element

1. Below `ake-class2` inherits from/extends `ake-class1`.
2. Adding `<select>` element to `ake-class2.shadowRoot`.
3. `console.log` `this.clickme` button to make sure it's inherited correctly.
4. `clickme` button doesn't work without adding again lines after comment `These 3 lines` in `ake-class2`.

I couldn't understand why this behavior happen.
why this happpens ?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AKE Front</title>
        <script>
            class1_html = `
            <div class="container">
            <button class="clickme">Click Me</button>
            </div>
            `
            class2_html = `
            <select></select>
            `
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            class AKEclass1 extends HTMLElement  { //custom-component class
                constructor() {
                    super(); // always call super() first in the constructor.
                    //const root = this.createShadowRoot(); //chrome only - deprecated
                    const root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); //By calling attachShadow with mode: 'open', we are telling our element to save a reference to the shadow root on the element.shadowRoot property
                    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = class1_html;
                    // These 3 lines
                    this.container = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.container");
                    this.clickme = this.container.querySelector("button.clickme");
                    this.clickme.addEventListener("click", this.clickMe.bind(this));
                }
                clickMe() {
                    alert("Hello !");
                }
            }
            customElements.define('ake-class1', AKEclass1);
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            class AKEclass2 extends AKEclass1 { //custom-component class
                constructor() {
                    super(); // always call super() first in the constructor.
                    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML += class2_html;
                    // These 3 lines
                    //this.container = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div.container");
                    //this.clickme = this.container.querySelector("button.clickme");
                    //this.clickme.addEventListener("click", this.clickMe.bind(this));
                }
            }
            customElements.define('ake-class2', AKEclass2);
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ake-class2 class="ake_window"></ake-class2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to give you a hint: removing `this.shadowRoot.innerHTML += class2_html;` will make the button work again...

Comment: Yes I know, but this is not the requirement. @RickardElimää

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `.innerHTML +=`  is the culprit.

What it does:

- Create a NEW string by concatening `.innerHTML + NEWString`
- delete the innerHTML DOM tree
  *and then Garbage Collection (GC) kicks in:*

  - Delete all existing DOM elements, **thus *remove* all connected listeners**
- set the NEW String as innerHTML

Some 'gurus' say this makes `innerHTML` evil, I say you need to understand what it does.

---

In the SO snippet below you see the listener being connected **twice**, but only executed **once** when clicked

```html
<script>
  class BaseClass extends HTMLElement { 
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
             .innerHTML = `<button>Click ${this.nodeName}</button>`;
      this.listen();// but removed by GC
    }
    listen(){
      console.log("add listener on", this.nodeName);
      this.shadowRoot
          .querySelector("button")
          .onclick = (evt) => this.clicked(evt); 
    }
    clicked(evt){
        console.log("clicked", this.nodeName)
    }
  }
  //customElements.define('element-1', BaseClass);
  customElements.define('element-2', class extends BaseClass {
    connectedCallback(){
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML += ` with concatenated HTML`;
      this.listen();
    }
  });
</script>
<element-2></element-2>
```

Notes:

- Using the **inline** `onclick` handler, it only allows for one handler where `addEventListener` can add more (you can use it here if you like)
- No need for oldskool `.bind(this)` by defining lexical scope with a **arrow function**, not a function **reference**
- all can be chained because

  - `super()` sets AND returns the `this` scope
  - `attachShadow` sets AND returns `this.shadowRoot`

Comment: Well written and detailed answer. Thanks a lot @Danny